# Nginx Caching max-age=0

Tags: caching, nginx

I believe that the caching on my Nginx server is set up correctly but on the header when checking in firebug I am seeing 'Cache-Control:max-age=0'.

I am assuming this means that the cache is not working correctly. Any ideas?

Edit 29/10/15:
The server is set for smart static files processing and also to seve static files directly by nginx. Here are the additional directives currently being used.

```
# BEGIN W3TC Minify cache
location ~ /wp-content/cache/minify.*\.js$ {
types {}
default_type application/x-javascript;
add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
expires 30d;
}
location ~ /wp-content/cache/minify.*\.css$ {
types {}
default_type text/css;
add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
expires 30d;
}
location ~ /wp-content/cache/minify.*js\.gzip$ {
gzip off;
types {}
default_type application/x-javascript;
add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
}
location ~ /wp-content/cache/minify.*css\.gzip$ {
gzip off;
types {}
default_type text/css;
add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
}
# END W3TC Minify cache
# BEGIN W3TC Minify core
rewrite ^/wp-content/cache/minify.*/w3tc_rewrite_test$ /wp-content   /plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/minify.php?w3tc_rewrite_test=1 last;
set $w3tc_enc "";
if ($http_accept_encoding ~ gzip) {
set $w3tc_enc .gzip;
}
if (-f $request_filename$w3tc_enc) {
rewrite (.*) $1$w3tc_enc break;
}
rewrite ^/wp-content/cache/minify/(.+/[X]+\.css)$ /wp-content/plugins    /w3-total-cache/pub/minify.php?test_file=$1 last;
rewrite ^/wp-content/cache/minify/(.+\.(css|js))$ /wp-content/plugins    /w3-total-cache/pub/minify.php?file=$1 last;
# END W3TC Minify core
location ~* \.(js|css|svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
expires 30d;
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
log_not_found off;
access_log off;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that it's not working correctly? Is it a header from response or from request?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken and my apologies if my terminology is errant, this means that the site is being loaded afresh every time. It exists both on the response and request headers. Here is the website in question: [link](https://www.boxchilli.com/)

Comment: Did you hit refresh button (F5/cmd-R/etc.)?

Comment: No, I read that that might be an issue so I also accessed the site via a link. This behaviour still exists. If you follow the link, you will see, it is my web design site so no risks.

Comment: Check your backend if it sends caching headers. Also, show nginx's config in quesion.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have added the server config above. If this is not the information you are looking for, please let me know and I will provide whatever you require. Thanks :)